# Multiple countdowns on one page (js / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to place few (from 5 to 25) simple countdowns on one page and browser crashes (100% CPU load)

Help somebody pls!

```
function timersInit(){
    $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
        var timerObject = $(this),
            time_left_nix = parseInt(timerObject.data('countdown')),
            time_left_h = Math.floor(time_left_nix / 3600),
            time_left_m = Math.floor((time_left_nix / 60) - (time_left_h * 60)),
            time_left_s = Math.floor(time_left_nix - (time_left_m * 60) - (time_left_h * 3600));

        timerObject.text(time_left_h + ":" + (time_left_m < 10 ? "0" + time_left_m : time_left_m) + ":" + time_left_s);
    });

    setTimeout(timersInit(), 1000);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(timersInit(), 1000);` ==> `setTimeout(timersInit, 1000);`, `$('[data-countdown]')` ==> `$('[data-countdown]:visible')`

Comment: Put it on answer .... I'll check as correct answer ....

Comment: there is so idiotic mistake in my code .... 6AM ... need2sleep )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the function `timersInit()` is being called immediately infinitely.

Notice that the function is called immediately inside `setTimeout` and the returned value is used as function to call after the timeout. This is causing the function to call recursively infinitely until the browser is hanged.

```
function timersInit() {

    ....

    setTimeout(timersInit(), 1000);
    // timersInit(): means call immediately
}
```

To solve the problem, you can use the function reference instead of calling it.

```
setTimeout(timersInit, 1000); // Removed `()` of `timersInit`
```

---

To improve the performance bit, I'll suggest to cache the elements and loop over only visible elements.

```
var countdownEl = $('[data-countdown]:visible'); // Cache

function timersInit() {
    countdownEl.text(function () { // Use cached version instead of diving into DOM
        var time_left_nix = parseInt($(this).data('countdown')),
            time_left_h = Math.floor(time_left_nix / 3600),
            time_left_m = Math.floor((time_left_nix / 60) - (time_left_h * 60)),
            time_left_s = Math.floor(time_left_nix - (time_left_m * 60) - (time_left_h * 3600));

        return time_left_h + ":" + (time_left_m < 10 ? "0" + time_left_m : time_left_m) + ":" + time_left_s;
    });

    setTimeout(timersInit, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thx for help! 
there is so idiotic mistake in my code .... 6AM ... need2sleep )))